# How can I integrate my Bot (created with the Bot Framework) with Spark?

Tags: bots, botframework

I have a bot that I created using the Microsoft Bot Framework, and I would like to communicate with it via [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/index.jsp). I know that Spark uses XMPP (which I have no experience with) and it isn't supported by the Bot Connector. However I would like to know if there's a way around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the botframework has Direct Line for generic REST access, you could potentially write a botframework-directline-spark bridge.

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/

If you have the time to invest, perhaps start an OSS XMPP-Botframework? There are a few XMPP IMs out there that might be interested in working on this.